# Passing multiple values to key in dict

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml

I have following piece of dict and I would like to pass multiple paths into **args**. How can I do that. In  a nutshell, what I want is passing multiple values to __args__keys.
I am passing these values via config.yaml file.

```
   'validate': {'batch_size': 24,
                                  'dataset': {'_target_': 'basic_classifier.dataset.FolderBasedClassification',
                                              'folder': {'_args_': ['training/datasets/christmas2020/validation/'],
                                                         '_target_': 'pathlib.Path'},
                                              'input_size': '${input_size}'}}},
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did using an array is probably the good way. What you can do is :

```
{'_args_': ['training/datasets/christmas2020/validation/',
 'training/datasets/christmas2020/foo/',
 'training/datasets/christmas2020/bar/']}
```

Comment: I tried this way but it throws error. for better explanation of problem [Link} (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73004819/passing-multiple-path-to-arg-in-hydra-utils-config-file)

Comment: With no context on how you want to use your dict it's impossible to help you, the link you provided looks like a good solution.